# if condition inside Insert query in excel?

Tags: mysql, excel

i'm trying to turn my records in excel into an insert query.
i've fields empty in certain situations. In such case, NULL should be inserted.
I've written the formula as below but it is not working/showing error.
Think i've missed something.

`="INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(" &A2 &",'" & B2 & "','"&C2&"','"&D2&"',"&E2&","&F2&", IF((ISBLANK(G2)), "Null", '" & G2 & "'),'" & H2 & "','" & I2 & "');"`

in ablove formula, i'm checking `G2` cell is empty or not.
is this correct way to do else someother way is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generally not try and amalgamate so much together in a standard cell in this way - it tends to cause confusion (as you have found)

With that in mind, the below appears to do what you want:

```
="INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES("&A2&",'"&B2&"','"&C2&"','"&D2&"',"&E2&","&F2&", "&IF(ISBLANK(G2),"Null","'"&G2&"'")&",'"&H2&"','"&I2&"');"
```

You had some extra brackets and quotes than it appears were required.

I would probably try chaining between cells ( I generally write SQL queries in VBA and build them up line by line)

I hope that this helps

Comment: Brilliant :) glad it does. Another thing I forgot to mention is that you needed to do another & after the apostrophes before the IF, otherwise it gets confused hehe